# c++ template and its element type

Tags: c++, templates

This is my template matrix class:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
....
Matrix<T> operator / (const T &num);
}
```

However, in my Pixel class, I didn't define the Pixel/Pixel operator at all!

Why in this case, the compiler still compiles?

Pixel class

```
#ifndef MYRGB_H
#define MYRGB_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Pixel
{
public:
    // Constructors
    Pixel();
    Pixel(const int r, const int g, const int b);
    Pixel(const Pixel &value);
    ~Pixel();

    // Assignment operator
    const Pixel& operator = (const Pixel &value);

    // Logical operator
    bool operator == (const Pixel &value);
    bool operator != (const Pixel &value);

    // Calculation operators
    Pixel operator + (const Pixel &value);
    Pixel operator - (const Pixel &value);
    Pixel operator * (const Pixel &value);
    Pixel operator * (const int &num);
    Pixel operator / (const int &num);

    // IO-stream operators
    friend istream &operator >> (istream& input, Pixel &value);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream& output, const Pixel &value);

private:
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Please include the compiler error you're seeing.  You also mention a Pixel class that you don't show any code for.

It looks like you're defining a '/' operator on your matrix class, one which takes a T element on the right side.  You don't show the body of that method, so it's doubly hard to know why you'd expect a compiler error.

More info, please.

Comment: @Neil added the Pixel class. Thanks.

Comment: You should never be `using namespace std` in a header.

Comment: By the way, I think the assignment operator typically returns a non-const reference.

Comment: You only show class declarations. I have no idea why you think they shouldn't compile.

Comment: @tony: The C++ world is somewhat divided about this. Although I happen to agree with you, I cannot deny that there are good reasons to make it return a `const` reference.

Comment: @sbi:  I didn't think it was that divided.  Obviously the object being assigned to is not const...  But I suppose.  Obviously not relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @tony: Returning a `const` reference prevents `a=b=c` from compiling, which is rarely ever used intentionally. Some people want to prevent this, others stick to "do as the ints do" and want this to compile. I'm in the latter camp, but I'm not fanatic about it.

Comment: yeah I was thinking that a=b=c was the reason to *want* non-const.  I can honestly say I've never mixed up = and == (in 20+ years), but maybe if I was mixing my languages more I would...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ templates are instantiated at the point you use them, and this happens for the `Matrix<T>::operator/(const T&)`, too. This means the compiler will allow `Matrix<Pixel>`, unless you ever invoke the division operator.

Comment: I would rather say that it would not allow `Matrix<Pixel>::operator/` to be called, because all source files that reference `Matrix<Pixel>` without ever mentioning the `operator/` will continue to compile.

Answer (score 0):

1) You didn't provide body of Matrix operator, so it is possible that Pixel/Pixel operator isn't needed.

2) Afaik, template methods do not generate compile errors unless you call them somewhere in your code. NO idea if this is standard or not, but some versions of MSVC behave this way. Do

```
Matrix m;
Pixel p;
m = m/p
```

somewhere in your code, and see what happens.